# How to allow special characters for a password in Laravel?

Tags: php, validation, laravel

By default Laravel's validator has alpha, apha_num, apha_dash. All three of which can't check for special characters, so if I set any of them for the password field, it always gives me an error if the password has a special character. Does anybody know how to allow special characters in validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest just not using anything there except required and maybe a min length (min:6 iirc). That way the user can enter whatever they like, numbers, letters or special characters...

My question would be what are you trying to prevent?

Comment: I want to do just that, but there are some characters that people recommend we shouldn't allow, do you think they are right? Or should I just allow everything?

Comment: @FlawidD'Souza I would just allow everything because it's going to get hashed anyway... it's not like this is content you are going to output. Just set it to required, and consider a min lenght.

Comment: That's what I did. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.
You need to edit some things in the like the min() password length, etc...

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password;
...

$request->validate([
    'password' => [
        'required',
        'confirmed',
        Password::min(8)
            ->mixedCase() // allows both uppercase and lowercase
            ->letters() //accepts letter
            ->numbers() //accepts numbers
            ->symbols() //accepts special character
            ->uncompromised(), //check to be sure that there is no data leak
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression as a validator.

```
'field' => 'regex:A-Za-z0-9\!-_'
```

Add the special characters you want to allow after the `0-9` part of the expression.

Comment: this will not work.